# How to update component state on through out redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to showing modal when user click the edit button. I setup editProject action. When user clicked the edit button, editProject returns true.

But we can turns redux state into props not component states. Then how can we dynamicly update component state when props are changed ?

Here is EditProjectForm component

```
import React from "react";
import {Modal, Button, Form} from "react-bootstrap"
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {updateProject} from "../../actions";

class EditProjectForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {status: true}
    }

    onCloseClick() {
        this.setState({status: false})
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        //TODO update project
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal show={this.state.status} onHide={this.onCloseClick}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>{this.props.project.title}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}
                          style={{backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5", paddingBottom: 30}}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="title" style={{margin: 10}}>
                            <Form.Label column>Project Title</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter a title"/>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="description" style={{margin: 10}}>
                            <Form.Label column>Project Description</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="textarea" placeholder="Enter description"/>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="float-right" style={{marginRight: 10}}>
                            Save
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.onCloseClick}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}

const mapper = function (state) {
    return {
        status: state.editProject,
        project: state.selectProject
    }
};

export default connect(mapper, {updateProject})(EditProjectForm)
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that you need to decide where do you want your state to live? In the component scope or in the global scope, i.e., Redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways I think,

1- You can use Redux state this.props.status directly in your component instead of this.state.status, this way you would dispatch an action on **onCloseClick** that would update Redux store and change status to false.

2- Though it's not recommended usually, You can drive state from props using life **getDerivedStateFromProps** as

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
  return {
           status: props.status
  }
}
```

Now your component's internal state is derived from props.

You can read more about getDerivedStateFromProps [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Hope it helps

Comment: first option make more sense, thank you for the answer mate

Answer (score 0):

When you connect this component to the store you can access the `status` using the `this.props.status` and to update the status you need an action ex `updateStatus` please read more about the actions:
https://redux.js.org/basics/actions

```
import React from "react";
import {Modal, Button, Form} from "react-bootstrap"
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {updateProject} from "../../actions";

class EditProjectForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal show={this.props.status} onHide={this.onCloseClick}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>{this.props.project.title}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}
                          style={{backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5", paddingBottom: 30}}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="title" style={{margin: 10}}>
                            <Form.Label column>Project Title</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter a title"/>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="description" style={{margin: 10}}>
                            <Form.Label column>Project Description</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="textarea" placeholder="Enter description"/>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="float-right" style={{marginRight: 10}}>
                            Save
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.onCloseClick}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}

const mapper = function (state) {
    return {
        status: state.editProject,
        project: state.selectProject
    }
};

export default connect(mapper, {updateProject})(EditProjectForm)
```

Comment: You should add some notes to explain your changes rather than just dump a load of code.

Comment: then how I'm gonna close the model when user click the close button ?